# SageMaker: transform endpoint output with pretrained model

Tags: amazon-web-services, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I have a pretrained XgBoost Model for multilabel classification, I can deploy it as an endpoint using `create_model`, `create_endpoint_configuration` and `create_endpoint` functions of sagemaker client. When it is invoked it returns a list of probabilities for each label.

Now I want to transform the endpoint output from the list of probabilities to actual labels representing those probabilities.

I know I can use XGBoost estimator and `entry_point` to write my own `output_fn`. But I would still like to use the sagemaker client functions as they provide more control for our CI/CD pipeline.

How can use `entry_point` (or something similar) in sagemaker client functions I am already using?

Comment: Difficult to understand for question, please use a simple way to explain.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You can build own xgboost image to run your model. I mean you update code, build image and push to ECR, then use it as sagemaker image

This is how aws build xgboost image. https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-xgboost-container

Some useful links:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container
 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html
 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo.html